# how to cleanly handle errors in nextjs getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm very busy at the moment with building my first Next.JS application (Next and Strapi). Now everything is working but i'm curious about what the best way is to implement error handling when using `getStaticProps`.

I tried a few things myself (passing multiple props etc, but that all didn't work (typical unserialized JSON error). The thing I want to achieve is an error message on the page itself (e.g. /about) that no data was found. With an error message attached (statusCode).

I hope it's possible, I did a lot research and found: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/17755 this. But it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can create [custom 404 and 500 error pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page).  There is an option to show the [statusCode](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#more-advanced-error-page-customizing) however, you can tell Next to use the 404 page by returning `notfound: true` in `getStaticProps`.

If you return `notfound: true`, the statusCode will always show the 404 page, and you know the status code will be 404.

Here is a example of catching errors in `getStaticProps`- this will generate your page or show your custom error page that is designed to your specifications.

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  try {
    const { data, errors } = await someQuery();
    if (errors || !data) {
      return { notFound: true };
    }
    return { props: { data } };
  } catch () {
    return { notFound: true };
  }
};
```

---

A not so obvious additional use case of `notFound` is to use it to exclude a directory or page from production.  The below check will skip the whole page or directory during next/export (SSG).  This check be used to produce development only static pages.

If a single page in a directory has the check below, that page is skipped during the build process. If every page in a directory has the check - the whole directory will be skipped, including the folder.

```js
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    return { notFound: true };
  }
  ...
};
```

Make sure you don't include the routes you don't want built in `getStaticPaths` too.

Comment: Thankyou really much for your answer. This helped me a lot with understanding a proper way of error handling in next. Problem is solved.

Comment: This is not a proper solution with all respect. I am interested and researching a proper solution to report the undhandled exceptions in a montiroing system like newrelic/sentry anything. Do you have such a way for nextjs ? In previous apps in php and other frameworks was super easy but now am struggling to find a way capture all unhandled exceptions regardless of where happen in server side , maybe in getstaticprops or elsewhere want to capture and report them

Comment: Since getStaticProps runs at build time, as I understand it try-catch is unnecessary and should generally be handled internally by next.js. 404 errors can of course occur at run-time hence should these be checked for as in the example above.

Comment: It's a top-level function in my project, so I call the try-catch there; I'm not sure if Next allows the build to continue when errors occur, and you don't handle them.

Comment: Your example redirects **all** errors to 404. Isn't it better to rethrow non-404 errors so they redirect to the 500 page?

Comment: I avoid throwing 500 errors in production and use an error logger. This keeps it clean for users & search engines. Also, some popular ORMs throw errors instead of returning null when data doesn't exist. e.g., query based on a router query param. Since some ORMs prefer to throw by default, the user would get a 500 screen, not a 404, making the site look broken when the route doesn't exist. There are many ways to solve this problem. I found this to be the most straightforward and consistent method that has worked across several Next projects without modification.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

api.js

```
export async function fetcher(url, options = {}) {
  try {
    let response;
    if (!options) {
      response = await fetch(url);
    } else {
      response = await fetch(url, options);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
}
```

in pages/index.js

```
import { fetcher } from "/lib/api";
```

...

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { data, notFound } = await fetcher(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API}/homepage?publicationState=live&populate[seo][populate]=%2A&populate[pageHeading][populate]=%2A&populate[socialMedia][populate]=%2A&populate[block][populate]=%2A`
  );

  if (notFound) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return { props: { data } };
}
```

[image]