# nextjs dynamically set response header

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to create a blog for my website. Because I want to be able to dynamically add blogs without rebuilding I had to choose between incremental static generation and server-side rendering. Because a blog page won't change often, I decided to go for ISG. Of course, not every blog ID is a valid page. Therefor I want to set a status code, but I can't find out how without using server-side rendering

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [how to cleanly handle errors in nextjs getStaticProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67168743/how-to-cleanly-handle-errors-in-nextjs-getstaticprops)? You can return `{ notFound: true }` to display a 404 page for invalid blog IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Turns out I can return notFound: true from the getStaticProps to get a 404